# Apache Arrow C++: How to set nondefault options for the csv_reader in the official GitHub example "example.cc"?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow, csvreader

The example comes from [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp/examples/minimal_build).

The source file is [`example.cc`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/example.cc).

I was able to follow these [instructions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html) to build Arrow C++ on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS: out-of-source build with `cmake ..` and `make ..`.

And despite getting errors from running `build_arrow.sh` and `build_example.sh`, I managed to compile and run `example.cc` without using the bash scripts:

```js
g++ example.cc -o example -larrow
```

However, I got stuck trying to modify the **options** for the **csv_reader** on lines 40-42 of the source file `example.cc`.

I would like to know how the options could be set, in particularly, how to use a **char delimiter** other than the default `char delimiter = ','` for [`arrow::csv::ParseOptions`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html).

A complete, tested minimalist solution that could be run with the same shell commands above or simiar would be much appreciated, as would be references for further study.

For completeness, the source code is copied below in full (and I will delete it if license infringement has been inadvertently committed):

```js
// Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
// or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
// distributed with this work for additional information
// regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
// to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
// "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
// with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
// software distributed under the License is distributed on an
// "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
// KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
// specific language governing permissions and limitations
// under the License.

#include <arrow/csv/api.h>
#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/api.h>
#include <arrow/pretty_print.h>
#include <arrow/result.h>
#include <arrow/status.h>
#include <arrow/table.h>

#include <iostream>

using arrow::Status;

namespace {

Status RunMain(int argc, char** argv) {
  const char* csv_filename = "test.csv";
  const char* arrow_filename = "test.arrow";

  std::cerr << "* Reading CSV file '" << csv_filename << "' into table" << std::endl;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto input_file, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(csv_filename));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto csv_reader, arrow::csv::TableReader::Make(
                                             arrow::io::default_io_context(), input_file,
                                             arrow::csv::ReadOptions::Defaults(),
                                             arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults(),
                                             arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults()));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto table, csv_reader->Read());

  std::cerr << "* Read table:" << std::endl;
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(arrow::PrettyPrint(*table, {}, &std::cerr));

  std::cerr << "* Writing table into Arrow IPC file '" << arrow_filename << "'"
            << std::endl;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto output_file,
                        arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(arrow_filename));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto batch_writer,
                        arrow::ipc::MakeFileWriter(output_file, table->schema()));
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(batch_writer->WriteTable(*table));
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(batch_writer->Close());

  return Status::OK();
}

}  // namespace

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Status st = RunMain(argc, argv);
  if (!st.ok()) {
    std::cerr << st << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Mimimal Reproducible Example** (as suggested by relent95)

*Step 1: Building Arrow C++*

Cf the [instructions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html).

```js
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
$ cd arrow/cpp
$ mkdir build   # from inside the `cpp` subdirectory
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make ..
```

*Step 2: Compile and run `arrow/cpp/examples/minimal_build/example.cc`*

Make folder `build` inside `arrow/cpp/examples/minimal_build/`

```js
$ # from inside the `arrow/cpp/examples/minimal_build/build` subdirectory
$ g++ ../example.cc -o example -larrow
```

Stay inside the `build` folder, copy `test.csv`, and run the executable `example`

```js
$ cp ../test.csv .
$ ./example
```

The executable `example` would run to produce the expected output `test.arrow`.

*Step 3: Get error from modifying `ParseOptions`*

- Make a copy of `example.cc` in the `arrow/cpp/examples/minimal_build/build` subdirectory, rename it `myexample.cc`
- As suggested, add, on line 29 (above `namespace`), the **two** statements below:

```js
auto parse_opts = arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults(); parse_opts.delimiter = '\t';
```

- Inside the `.../miniml_build/build` subdirectory, compiling `myexample.cc` with `g++ myexample.cc -o myexample -larrow` would throw an error `'parse_opts does not name a type`
- Comments: One can comment out the **second** statement on line 29, include the header file `<typeinfo>`, and print `typeid(parse_opts).name()` to see that `parse_opts` is of type `N5arrow3csv12ParseOptionsE`.
- For completeness and clarity, the code in `myexample.cc` is copied below in full:

```js
// Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
// or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
// distributed with this work for additional information
// regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
// to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
// "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
// with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
// software distributed under the License is distributed on an
// "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
// KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
// specific language governing permissions and limitations
// under the License.

#include <arrow/csv/api.h>
#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/api.h>
#include <arrow/pretty_print.h>
#include <arrow/result.h>
#include <arrow/status.h>
#include <arrow/table.h>

#include <iostream>

using arrow::Status;
auto parse_opts = arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults(); parse_opts.delimiter = '\t';
namespace {

Status RunMain(int argc, char** argv) {
  const char* csv_filename = "test.csv";
  const char* arrow_filename = "test.arrow";

  std::cerr << "* Reading CSV file '" << csv_filename << "' into table" << std::endl;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto input_file, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(csv_filename));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto csv_reader, arrow::csv::TableReader::Make(
                                             arrow::io::default_io_context(), input_file,
                                             arrow::csv::ReadOptions::Defaults(),
                                             arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults(),
                                             arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults()));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto table, csv_reader->Read());

  std::cerr << "* Read table:" << std::endl;
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(arrow::PrettyPrint(*table, {}, &std::cerr));

  std::cerr << "* Writing table into Arrow IPC file '" << arrow_filename << "'"
            << std::endl;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto output_file,
                        arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(arrow_filename));
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto batch_writer,
                        arrow::ipc::MakeFileWriter(output_file, table->schema()));
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(batch_writer->WriteTable(*table));
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(batch_writer->Close());

  return Status::OK();
}

}  // namespace

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Status st = RunMain(argc, argv);
  if (!st.ok()) {
    std::cerr << st << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message: [the *type* error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MJyH.png)

Comment: You need to edit for conciseness.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Yes, please do what Adriaan said. Also in your code, you put a statement in the global scope. It's just a syntax error. I don't recommend the C++ API of Arrow if you are not familiar with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ParseOptions` is a struct, so use the plain C++ syntax, like this.

```
auto parse_opts = arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults();
parse_opts.delimiter = '\t';
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto csv_reader, arrow::csv::TableReader::Make(
...
    parse_opts,
    arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that was what I tried before posting my question. It won't work because while the definition `auto  parse_opts = ...;` was fine, the updating `parse_opts.delimiter = '\t';` threw an error `'parse_opts' does not name a type`. Somewhat strange, without the updating the delimiter, `typeid(parse_opts)` would reveal a type of `N5arrow3csv12ParseOptionsE`. A tested solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Then you should provide a [mre] and debugging details. I am CERTAIN you have done something wrong in some other place of your code.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The option-setting statements have to be in the scope of `Status RunMain`. They cannot be global or in between `namespace` and `Status RunMain`. Many thanks.

Comment: To leave no doubt, the solution is, as suggested, to put the option-setting statements inside `Status RunMain(){...}`.